# Picard approximations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm homelearning calculus and trying to solve the following problem:

> Find the first two Picard approximations for the solution of the
> equation:
>
> $x''=(x')^2x$
>
> so that conditions are met: $x(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $x'(0)=0$

However, I'm not sure how to calculate it for a differential equation of second degree. I only know it for the first degree. Could you please help me or give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always in the general theory or in the application of general solvers, you transform into a first-order system
$$
x'=y,\\
y'=xy^2.
$$
Then the initial conditions transfer to the initial constant approximations
$$
x_0(t)=x_0=-\frac12,\\
y_0(t)=y_0=0.
$$
Now you can iterate the Picard-iteration
$$
x_1(t)=x_0+\int_0^ty_0(s)\,ds,\\
y_1(t)=y_0+\int_0^tx_0(s)y_0(s)^2\,ds,
$$
then
$$
x_2(t)=x_0+\int_0^ty_1(s)\,ds,\\
y_2(t)=y_0+\int_0^tx_1(s)y_1(s)^2\,ds,
$$

etc.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask how did you get $x'=y$ and $y'=xy^2$?

Comment: @Emanuel Simply defining
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}&=y, \ \ \ \text{and taking a derivative gives}\\
\frac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dt^2}&=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}.
\end{align}
Plugging the above two into your ODE gives that
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=y^2x.
\end{align}

Comment: @Eli Could you please explain it further? I don't get it

Comment: @Emanuel : What step precisely? The idea to perform the higher order differentiation in steps? How replacing $x'$ with $y$ and thus $x''$ with $y'$ works?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I didn't understand that you can simply define $\frac{dx}{dt}=y$ but I understand now.